# Necessitas QT - installing shared QT libraries on a device

Tags: android, qt, deployment, libraries

I have a reasonably large Qt project which I don't want to rewrite in Java for Android. So I downloaded and installed Necessitas SDK and managed to compile the project as an apk file.

So far so good. It also executed successfully in emulator, but then I got stuck. First problem was that Necessitas Qt Creator always produces a "Debug" apk file, even though I set the project config to "Release". The second problem, it allows me to deploy the app to emulator only, but I want to install and test it on a real Android device.

How can I find and copy the necessary Qt libraries manually to the device?

Answer (score 2):

Install **Ministro** from the Market to get the Qt libraries. Your app will dialog with Ministro to get the needed libraries from the net. See the [How to write Qt apps for Android](http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/wiki/How%20to%20write%20Qt%20apps%20for%20Android) guides for more information.

Necessitas is still alpha, so the libraries are indeed debug ones (to get debug messages), but stripped of the symbols.

Comment: Thank you, but I really need an offline/manual way to install the libraries. This app is for e-Ink devices, which are not always connected to the Internet.

Comment: There is no way yet to install the Qt libs on Android without an internet connection, sorry.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I guess I will rewrite the UI part in Java then and use Android NDK for the rest.